# Drools Firing Rules for all event when loading persisted session

Tags: drools, drools-fusion

I am storing drools session using `KieMarshler`. When I am loading the persisted session. Drools is firing all the rule for all the event that is there in the loaded session. Below is the rule:

```
rule "1"
when
        TestEvent()
then
        System.out.println("Rule 1 Fired");
end
```

Comment: Your rule says "if there is any event in working memory, fire this rule." Why do you expect the rule not to fire?

Comment: @RoddyoftheFrozenPeas   If the working memory has already fired for that event. Then it should not fire the rule again if I am loading the persisted session.